# ValueError: c argument has n elements, which is not acceptable for use with x with size 0, y with size 0

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, valueerror

I am trying to plot a scatterplot using matplotlib/seaborn:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
sns.scatterplot(
    x=[i[0] for i in tsne_data],
    y=[i[1] for i in tsne_data],
    alpha=0.3,
    color=label_colors
)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument has 267794 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 0, 'y' with size 0.
```

My data:

- `label_colors` — a Python list with 267,794 elements. Each element is a string, e.g. 'red', 'blue', 'purple'.
- `tsne_data` — a Numpy 2D array with 267,794 elements. Each element is a x, y coordinate, e.g. `[  9.417695 , -25.48891  ]`. Shaped as (267794, 2).

I can't understand why I'm getting this error, especially why 'x' and 'y' are not recognized as having any length. I have attempted this with a pandas dataframe instead, where I have an 'x' and 'y' column, then setting `x=df['x']` or `x=list(df['x'])` but I get the same error. How can I plot my `tsne_data` so that each of its 267,794 point is colored by the color specified at its corresponding index in `label_colors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) you should use the param `hue` for example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
sns.scatterplot(
    x=[i[0] for i in tsne_data],
    y=[i[1] for i in tsne_data],
    alpha=0.3,
    hue=label_colors
)
```